# How to send multipart/form-data in target.request in java

Tags: java

I have a post request being sent in the following manner:

```
final private ObjectMapper mapper;
...
Client client=target;
...
Response response =target.request().post(Entity.entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(feedbackFilterDataForDA),
                    APPLICATION_JSON));
```

And the request goes to a function of type:

```
public Response getData(FeedbackFilterDataForDA f,ArrayList<String> a) {
}
```

How to change the target.request() to take two parameters with the help of multipart/form-data?

Comment: You question is not very explanatory. what is **target** in you code? Try posting the full code snippet

Comment: It is of type Client

Comment: I would suggest you to post atleast understandable block of code, where we can know what variables and references are and how you have defined them.